# OS X, packet filter (PF), route-to options

Tags: macos, networking, routing, pf

I was trying to setup "policy based" routing with pfctl (PF) on OS X 10.10, however no matter what i do, i am getting "syntax error" from pfctl. config is rather simple:

```
cat ./test.conf

inf="en0"
outf="en1"
inn="192.168.1.0/24"
outg="192.168.2.1"

pass in on $inf from $inn route-to ( $outf, $outg )
--

pfctl -n -v -f ./test.conf
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

inf = "en0"
outf = "en1"
inn = "192.168.1.0/24"
outg = "192.168.2.1"
230.conf:6: syntax error
```

anyone know proper syntax, route option is just not implemented/supported on OS X ?

thanks

**update: proper syntax (and empty line) will be

pass in on $inf route-to ( $outf $outg ) from $inn
**

Answer (score 3):

after bumping my head for hours, i figured out proper syntax and what was wrong.
1. really stupid (imo) pf parses, you have to have EMPTY line after last non empty line. ie:

last rule pass parameters
!!! or you will get syntax error.

2. proper syntax for route-to should be
   pass in on $inf route-to ($outf $outg) from $inn
   slightly different from "regular" pass statement but made me hours to figure it out.